# How can I reset my form in C#?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form (in C#) which consists of buttons, picture boxes, labels that show information to users, and a combobox that the users can select data.

How can I add a refresh button that causes all my form changes to revert to their initial state when clicked? More specifically, how can I write a function that updates the form to have no data selected and initialized fields?

Comment: enumerate through controls and reset their values.

Comment: could you please let me how to reset for example my combobox? so i can have a idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not loading default state of your control from a database or any thing like that
you can reset it easily for example you can do this for a combobox:

```
this.comboBox.ResetText();
```

but if you are loading default state from a datasource i suggest you use Tag property of your control, its type is object.
i mean you should store default state of your control in Tag Property and when you want to restore that just cast Tag Proprty to what ever you want. see:

```
this.comboBox.Tag = myState;
```

and when you want to retrieve it:

```
MyClass class = (MyClass)this.comboBox.Tag;
```

or
    this.comboBox.Items.Add(this.comboBox.Tag);

there you go. tell me if you need more explain :)

Comment: how should i clear my image box from any current output?

Comment: just set Image Property to null, see: this.pictureBox.Image = null;

Comment: but the programme is still executing code on the background. first i need to stop running the programme in some way and then reset the items. could you please help me on that?

Comment: can you explain a bit more? i cant get the meaning of "Program is still executing in background"

Comment: basically my programme is rendering some images and show it to the user according to the input values. so when it is rendering images if i reset the input fields or if i reset the picture-box, it does not get new data and keep rendering the old data. for that reason i said basically i need to terminate the current process first and then reset the values.

Comment: you can prevent the user to reset the form when the app is processing images and fire up and event when you are done and let user to reset. lets say you can do some thing like this: this.pictureBox.LoadCompleted += (s, ea) => this.resetButton.Enabled = true;

Answer (score 1):

Use data bindings to bind your object to the form's controls. So by resetting the databound object to null all your controls on the form will be reset.

Here are some helpful links:

[A Detailed Data Binding Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)

[Data binding concepts in .NET windows forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3665/Data-binding-concepts-in-NET-windows-forms)

Comment: could you please give me some source to study more about that?

Comment: Better: Assign a new object having default values to the data source. Otherwise the newly entered values won't be stored.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added some helpful links for understanding databinding concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Markup

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox1" />
<asp:Button id="ResetBtn" OnClick="ResetBtn_Click" Text="Reset Form!" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox1.Text="Some random text";
    }
}

protected void ResetBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text="";
}
```

When the user clicks the button, you can set the value of the text box to whatever you want. In this case, empty.